How to build a recommendation system Based on user infos and without ratings?
I would like to build a recommendation system based only on user informations(age,sex,zipcode,and some quiz answers),based on those features i want to recommend assurance products, but i am confused because there is no feedback on my dataset, there is just the clients unfos and the name of the project bought.
i want to use machine learning or deep learning !
is it possible? if so what is the best method to deal with this type of data?
and what is the best algorithms should i try?!
